# Getting invalid url when using multiple types with nearbysearch Google web service

Tags: swift3

Getting *URL invalid* when I am trying to implement with multiple types like in query
**department_store|grocery_or_supermarket**

```
let query = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=28.965198333333333,77.98569833333333&radius=3218&type=department_store|grocery_or_supermarket&key=API_KEY"

guard let url = URL(string: query) else { return completion(.Failure("URL invalid")) }
```

While it is working fine with a single type

```
let query = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=28.965198333333333,77.98569833333333&radius=3218&type=grocery_or_supermarket&key=API_KEY"
```

Please suggest, how can I use multiple types with **nearbysearch** web service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved by using. guard let escapedQuery = query.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed),
      let url = URL(string: escapedQuery) else { return completion(.Failure("URL invalid")) }